# Remove typed item getting added into combobox list in Asp.net ajax?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, combobox

I have a ASP.NET AJAX ComboBox in one of my pages. Im binding data from DB. Now when i run this, since its a combobox we can type inside it. But after typing if you click any button the Typed Item will be added to the ComboBox List. I dont want that to be added?
How can I solve this?

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="ddlAccounts" runat="server" Width="130px" MaxLength="0" 
            meta:resourcekey="ddlAccountsResource1" style="display: inline;" 
            AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" ItemInsertLocation="OrdinalText">
        </asp:ComboBox>
```

how can i resolve this??

Answer (score 1):

You should use
`AutoCompleteMode="Suggest"` istead of `AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"`.

Take a look at example http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx.